# JavaScript: Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello i am new to java script. my group members had written some code for creating a website for a project and i wanted to run it on my laptop. We are using AngularJS for client side. But i am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\temp_course_rating\temp_course
_rating\public\app.js:2:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I have pasted the code from that particular file. I would really appreciate any help as i am way behind in my group:

```
var ratemycourse = {};
var App = angular.module('ratemycourse', ['ngResource']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl : '/templates/home.html',
   controller : HomeCtrl
 });

 $routeProvider.when('/register', {
  templateUrl : '/templates/register.html',
  controller : RegisterCtrl
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/login', {
   templateUrl : '/templates/login.html',
   controller : LoginCtrl
  });

 $routeProvider.when('/logout', {
   templateUrl : '/templates/logout.html',
   controller : LogoutCtrl
 });

$routeProvider.when('/mcgill', {
templateUrl : '/templates/mcgill.html',
//controller : McGillCtrl
 });

$routeProvider.when('/concordia', {
   templateUrl : '/templates/concordia.html',
   //controller : ConcordiaCtrl
  });

$routeProvider.when('/udem', {
   templateUrl : '/templates/udem.html',
//controller : UdemCtrl
 });
 $routeProvider.otherwise({
  redirectTo : '/'
 });
 }]);
```

Also following is the code file which calls angular.js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="ratemycourse">
      <head>
    <title>Rate My Courses</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"          href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/3.2.2/stylesheets/foundation.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    {{{block "stylesheets"}}}
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("mWF6nv6fLZx5l0FOYW8SSxfE07fcA4kMHPfl2UzR",       "m2N5pguJAwmEa6pEK1JwQ3nYqCg17K3PXIN3yCKK");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <nav class="top-bar" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
      <ul>

        <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="/"></a></li>
      </ul>
       <section>
         <ul class="left">

          <li><a href="#mcgill">McGill</a></li>
          <li><a href="#concordia">Concordia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#udem">UDEM</a></li>
        </ul>
         {{email}}
         <ul class="right">
          <li data-ng-hide="isLoggedIn"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
           <li data-ng-hide="isLoggedIn"><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
          <li data-ng-show="isLoggedIn"><a href="#logout">
            {{email}}</a></li>
          <li data-ng-show="isLoggedIn"><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>

    {{{body}}}

    <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\temp_course_rating\temp_course_rating\public\libs\angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\temp_course_rating\temp_course_rating\public\libs\angular-    resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/controller.js"></script>

    {{{block "scripts"}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` attribute of script tag should be url not file path
Instead of using path for javascipt source use url, like
change

```
src="C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\temp_course_rating\temp_course_rating\public\libs\angular.min.js">
```

to

```
src="http://localhost/yourproject/angular.min.js">
```

Comment: hello sudhir, 
i use the following link to download the angular.min.js file and hence i have to save it in a local directory. how can i get the url?? 

http://angularjs.org/

Comment: copy the angularjs files in your project folder and use url like: http://localhost/your_project/your_angular_jsfolder/angular.min.js

Comment: hello Sudhir, sorry but i really need ur help. Im trying to follow the instructions below but im getting a weird error
In a separate terminal tab or window, run node scripts\web-server.js to start the web server.

C:\Users\Usman>node scripts\web-server.js

module.js:340

    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Usman\scripts\web-server.js'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)

at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)

at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)

at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback  

(node.js:244:9)